# php, in_array and serialize() not working as expected

Tags: php, arrays, serialization

I have a list of contact for friends in a database, what I am trying to do is retrieve a users contacts, see if the other user id is in there, if it is not then add it then put it back in the database.

however I seem to keep adding the same contact into the array even when it is already thereand the output is stored in my db like this

```
a:2:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;i:1070;}i:1;i:1070;}
```

This is the product of the in_array not evaluating as true on the first check. Every time time the function is run more and more "layers" are added.

Thanks in advance

here is my code

```
function addfarmertohunter($hunterid,$farmerid){
    $select="SELECT contacts from users where id=$hunterid";
    $result=mysql_query($select)or die(' add farmer error'. mysql_error());
        if (mysql_num_rows($result)==1){
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $contacts=$row[0];  
        if($contacts==null||$contacts=="N;"||$contacts==""){
            $temp=array();
                        array_push($temp, $farmerid);
        }else{
            $temp=array(unserialize($contacts));
            if(in_array((int)$farmerid, $temp)==FALSE){array_push($temp, $farmerid);}
        }
        $strcontacts=serialize($temp);
        $ins="UPDATE users set contacts='$strcontacts' where id=$hunterid";
        mysql_query($ins) or die('add farmer e'.mysql_error());
        }
}
```

Comment: Why are you storing like that? Why not have a table with each contact in a row?

Comment: @Barmar what as in cols Farmerid. Hunterid, row1 1,2 row2,1,14?  would this be more efficient?

Comment: Yes, that's the preferred way to do it. Look up "relation table" and "many-to-many".

Comment: may be that would be a lot better, I have a feeling my current approach reflects that I have been writing php for 6 weeks, thanks for all your comments, they have been a real help

Comment: It's not a PHP issue, it's database design. Did you learn about "normalization" when studying databases (did you "learn" any of this stuff, or are you just picking it up as you go along)?

Comment: I read a book and no I am just picking it up as I go along, and I have done 9 or so apps (only been programming since Jan last year). now looking at the I can see the inherent flaws in this approach. most of the books I have read focus on syntax and not much on database design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First change this

$temp = array(unserialize($contacts));

$temp = unserialize($contacts);

and don't check with == or ==== in in_array try like this

if(in_array((int)$farmerid, $temp)){array_push($temp, $farmerid);}

OR

if(!in_array((int)$farmerid, $temp)){array_push($temp, $farmerid);}

Because returns TRUE if needle is found in the array, FALSE otherwise.

Comment: thanks that has fixed it

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
$temp = array(unserialize($contacts));
```

to:

```
$temp = unserialize($contacts);
```

`unserialize()` returns the array, so you're wrapping an extra level of array around it each time.